# Are any of the eligible bachelorettes Bards?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Call me odd, but I've come to enjoy the occasional encounters with female bards in certain bars around Skyrim.  Something about their songs just seems to add a bit of coziness to the environment.

I'm aware that you can be married in Skyrim (I already have an Amulet of Mara), but only to a certain sub-set of the single women in the world.

Are any of these eligible bachelorettes Bards?  If so:

- Which ones?
- If I marry one and ask her to move in with me, will she sing and play her songs in my house?

Comment: if all else fails... [force them!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39871/is-there-a-downside-when-i-force-someone-to-marry-me)

Comment: @desaivv I'm not sure I've been to Solitude's Inn yet.  There was another one recently though, that I grew a particular fondness for.  I'll have to look around and find her again to point you there, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly my friend as of this posting (and current DLC availability) there are no Bards you can marry, male or female. Since you stated you can't use console commands I need not include a listing of those... but here is a list of who you CAN marry.
Hope this is a consolation to your lamentations for a Bard so fair, well you get the picture, lol...

This is your link to marital bliss:

http://www.realsg.com/2011/11/guide-skyrim-marriage-how-to-and-list.html

It describes how to marry, who you can marry, conditions needed and locations.

Hope this helped

Comment: Ooh, there's a Priestess of Dibella available?  Too bad this is Skyrim, and not The Witcher.  ;-)

Comment: I so want to down-vote this answer, just because it's not the answer I wanted.

Comment: if it's any consolation my thoughts about marriage in Skyrim was like you to marry a bard so i could hear songs throughout the house,and they are prettier than most to boot,i settled for Ysolda from Whiterun instead...